# Thrust Counting Iterator inside Function

Tags: cuda, nvidia, thrust

Thank you very much for the answers at [Cuda Thrust Custom function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7483559/cuda-thrust-custom-function)

One last thing if I wanted to pass another vector to copy values such as this?

```
for (i=0;i<n;i++)
        for (j=0;j<n;j++)
            y[i*n+j]=h1[i]*a1[pos*n+j];
```

Its still not clear to me how to pass values to the function created Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure I follow the question. If you want the results in a different vector, can't you just use `thrust::copy` to make a copy of the input vector, then use `thrust::transform` with the function to do the operation in-place on the copy?

Comment: yep but its not just a regular copy... moreover It will have to pass the vector 2 times with this...
Couldnt i do this with a transform once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
thrust::transform(
    thrust::make_permutation_iterator(h1.begin(),
        thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::make_counting_iterator(0),
            IndexDivFunctor(n))),
    thrust::make_permutation_iterator(h1.begin(),
        thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::make_counting_iterator(0),
            IndexDivFunctor(n))) + n * n,
    thrust::make_permutation_iterator(a1.begin(),
        thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::make_counting_iterator(0),
            Indexa1Functor(n, pos))),
    y.begin(),
    thrust::multiplies<double>());
```